# RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php Issue after going from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have already done $php artisan key:generate and $php artisan config:cache. The key does generate in my .env file when doing the artisan generate command which is good.

I noticed this started after I updated from Laravel 5.1 to Laravel 5.2 and changed "bindshared" to "singleton" on my EncryptionServiceProvider.php which I was prompted to do when updating from 5.1 to 5.2.

I have been stumped on this for weeks now and can't seem to find anything helpful online. Thanks in advance!

Here is the error I am getting:

```
RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 45:
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.
in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 45
at EncryptionServiceProvider->getEncrypterForKeyAndCipher(null, null) in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 25
at EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(object(Application), array()) in Container.php line 731
at Container->build(object(Closure), array()) in Container.php line 629
at Container->make('encrypter', array()) in Application.php line 697
at Application->make('encrypter') in Container.php line 849
at Container->resolveClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 804
at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 774
at Container->build('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Container.php line 629
at Container->make('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Application.php line 697
at Application->make('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies') in Pipeline.php line 126
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 52
```

Here is my app.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'sign_image_dir' => 'img/signs/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'America/New_York',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => env('AES-256-CBC'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
    |
    */

    'log' => 'daily',


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Environment Value for Laravel 5.2 Update
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
        'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider',
        'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',
        'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider',
        'UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider',
        Collective\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
        'Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider',

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
        'Artisan'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
        'Auth'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
        'Blade'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
        'Bus'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus',
        'Cache'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
        'Config'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
        'Cookie'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
        'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
        'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
        'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
        'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'File'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'Hash'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
        'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
        'Inspiring' => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring',
        'Lang'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
        'Log'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
        'Mail'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
        'Password'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
        'Queue'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
        'Redirect'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
        'Redis'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
        'Request'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
        'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
        'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
        'Schema'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
        'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
        'Storage'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage',
        'URL'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
        'Validator' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
        'View'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
        'Flash'     => 'Laracasts\Flash\Flash',
        'PDF'       => 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade',
        'Image'     => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image',
        'Alert'     => 'UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlert',
        'Form'      => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
        'Html'      => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    ],

];
```

Here is the EncryptionServiceProvider.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Encryption;

use RuntimeException;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class EncryptionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('encrypter', function ($app) {
            $config = $app->make('config')->get('app');

            if (Str::startsWith($key = $config['key'], 'base64:')) {
                $key = base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
            }

            return $this->getEncrypterForKeyAndCipher($key, $config['cipher']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the proper encrypter instance for the given key and cipher.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  string  $cipher
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    protected function getEncrypterForKeyAndCipher($key, $cipher)
    {
        if (Encrypter::supported($key, $cipher)) {
            return new Encrypter($key, $cipher);
        } elseif (McryptEncrypter::supported($key, $cipher)) {
            return new McryptEncrypter($key, $cipher);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException('No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check these requirements satisfies or not .PHP version between 5.5.9 - 7.1.*,
OpenSSL PHP Extension,
PDO PHP Extension,
Mbstring PHP Extension,
Tokenizer PHP Extension,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'cipher' => env('AES-256-CBC'),` should be `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',`